# Which variant of Gnuplot to choose for OS X Moutain Lion ?

Tags: gnuplot, osx-mountain-lion, macports

I would like to know the best suited variant of Gnuplot that you recommend for Mac OS X Moutain Lion ? by the best, I mean the most performant for OS X and the one that avoid the use of X11.

```
port variants gnuplot
```

> - **[+]aquaterm**: Enable AquaTerm terminal
> - **emacs**: An emacs mode for working with gnuplot
> - **[+]luaterm**: Enable lua-based terminals
> - **no_x11**: Legacy compatibility variant
> - **[+]x11**: Enable X11 support
> - **[+]pangocairo**: Enable cairo-based terminals
> - **qt**: Enable qt terminal
> - **tutorial**: Build the tutorial (requires a tex install)
> - **universal**: Build for multiple architectures
> - **wxwidgets**: Enable wxt terminal (wxWidgets 2.8, 32-bit only)
> - **wxwidgets_devel**: Enable wxt terminal (using wxWidgets 2.9, supports 64-bit)

What the **[+]** stands for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with +aquaterm +pangocairo. Note that these aren't really variants -- It's still the same gnuplot -- It's just a matter of which back-end libraries gnuplot knows about to make plots on different "devices" (a device can be your screen using a terminal like aquaterm, or it can be a file using a terminal like postscript, png, pngcairo ...)

Comment: suppose I want to use Preview to visualize the produced charts ... the best solution will be **pangocairo** only ? how about the **qt** terminal ? does-it do the same thing like pangocairo ? ...

Comment: @ALJIMohamed -- `Preview` will handle all sorts of image types.  `postscript` for example is supported by `Preview` (although it will be converted to a pdf first).  Gnuplot will handle postscript pretty much however you decide to build it.